# Android Camera2 ImageReader size not correct on Android 5.0 Galaxy S5

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to apply Camera2 api to take a picture. I got right result on `Android 6.0.1` and `5.1.1` But not `5.0`.
I have no idea why.

```
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());

Size[] jpegSizes = null;

if (characteristics != null) {
    jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
}


if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
    width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
    height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
    Log.i("jpegSizes width : ", String.valueOf(width));
    Log.i("jpegSizes height : ", String.valueOf(height));
}


ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
        List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
        outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
        outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(new SurfaceTexture(10)));



final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE); //  TEMPLATE_VIDEO_SNAPSHOT


captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());


captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
```

And those are the sizes in jpegSizes array.

```
 I/takepic w :: 5312 h : 2988
 I/takepic w :: 3984 h : 2988
 I/takepic w :: 3264 h : 2448
 I/takepic w :: 3264 h : 1836
 I/takepic w :: 2560 h : 1920
 I/takepic w :: 2048 h : 1152
 I/takepic w :: 1920 h : 1080
 I/takepic w :: 1280 h : 960
 I/takepic w :: 1280 h : 720
 I/takepic w :: 800 h : 480
 I/takepic w :: 640 h : 480
```

I have tried all of them but always get this error:

> E/CameraDevice-0-LE: Surface with size (w=1, h=1) and format 0x1 is
>   not valid, size not in valid set: [1920x1080, 1440x1080, 1280x720,
>   1056x864, 960x720, 800x480, 720x480, 640x480, 352x288, 320x240,
>   176x144]
>
> W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed
>
> E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session;
>   configuration failed

Please get me any solution.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using **TextureView** instead of **AutoFitTextureView** solved the size problem on android 5.0. Hope it helps someone.